# how to use javascript to insert text at cursor position in asp.net MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm developing in asp.net and have a CKEDITOR on the screen with the cursor at a location that some text should be added.
A button exists on the page and when pressed will open a modalbox having textarea where user can insert text into it at the location the cursor was at the point when the button was pressed, but no text should be lost or replaced at the location of the cursor. 
Is this possible to in javascript

Answer (score 2):

you can pass the user input to the ckeditor's insertText or insertHtml function depending if you want to insert it as text or as html source. These will insert on the cursor/focus location in the editor.

so if the user input was something like:

```
    Some text and link: <a href="www.on47.com">on47</a>
```

insertText will place the user input as text. Even if it contains html, the content will be displayed as text and not clickable link so it will insert it as:

```
    Some text and link: <a href="www.on47.com">on47</a>
```

insertHtml will actually put it as html source so any hyperlinks will display as clickable links.

Some text and link: [on47](http://www.on47.com)

```
//you can get the user input from text area using javascript like below
var insertMe = document.getElementById('textAreaId').value;

//or using jquery as below
//var insertMe = $('#textAreaId').val();

//get your editor instance and insert the text or html
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.wckEditor;

editor.insertText(insertMe); 
            OR
//editor.insertHtml(insertMe);
```

let me know what version of ckeditor are you using ckeditor 4's insertHtml accepts second parameter which is optional and is set to html by default the insert mode the second parameter in the insertHtml is the mode which can be text, html, unfiltered_html etc.

```
 editor.insertHtml(insertMe, 'text');
```